# How to accurately plot the legend of multi-layer plot (boxplot and lineplot)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

data_box = np.random.random((10, 3))
data_line = np.random.random(3)

ax = sns.boxplot(data=data_box, color='red', saturation=0.5)
sns.lineplot(data=data_line, color='blue')
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='blue', lw=4, label='box'),
                   Patch(facecolor='red', edgecolor='grey', linewidth=1.5,
                         label='line')]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize='xx-large')
```

[image: sample plot]

I overlay a lineplot to a boxplot as in the image above, and draw the legend manually using matplotlib.

But seaborn sets the saturation of the colors, whose default value is 0.75 (I set it to 0.5 make the difference clear). So the legend color generated by matplotlib is not accurate. Is there any way to change the saturation of the matplotlib legend? Or how can I draw legend color accurately, except setting `saturation=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [seaborn's `desaturate`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.desaturate.html?highlight=desaturate#seaborn.desaturate) function

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

data_box = np.random.random((10, 3))
data_line = np.random.random(3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.boxplot(data=data_box, color='red', saturation=0.5)
sns.lineplot(data=data_line, color='blue')
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='blue', lw=4, label='box'),
                   Patch(facecolor=sns.desaturate('red',0.5), edgecolor='grey', linewidth=1.5,
                         label='line')]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize='xx-large')
```

[image]